# How to animate change when adding widget to the widget tree

Tags: animation, flutter

I have a stateful widget that shows a form including a checkbox. Part of the form (textfield for 'taxId') is only shown when the checkbox is active.

[Here's a mock of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHDKB.png)

I can change the state and retrigger the build to accomplish that. What I would like to do is animate the change. Instead of just appearing, I would like the new textfield to animate in (fade in and push the remaining widgets down). Is there a way to accomplish this through an implicit animation (similar to a UIStackView on iOS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing remaining widgets down we can use

```
AnimatedContainer(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  height: height,
  color: Color(0xff14ff65),
  child: Container(
      height: 50.0,
      child: yourchild,),
    ),
)
```

put that TextField as your child and on checkbox change listener

```
setState((){
//increment and decrement height of AnimatedContainer
})
```